# How to check if a dict value contains a word/string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple condition where i need to check if a dict value contains say `[Complted]` in a particular key.

**example** :

```
'Events': [
                {
                    'Code': 'instance-reboot'|'system-reboot'|'system-maintenance'|'instance-retirement'|'instance-stop',
                    'Description': 'string',
                    'NotBefore': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
                    'NotAfter': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
                },
            ],
```

I need to check if the `Description` key contains `[Complted]` in it at starting. i.e

> 'Descripton': '[Completed] The instance is running on degraded
>   hardware'

How can i do so ?  I am looking for something like

```
if inst ['Events'][0]['Code'] == "instance-stop":
      if inst ['Events'][0]['Description'] consists   '[Completed]":
              print "Nothing to do here"
```

Comment: What is this line supposed to do?
`'Code': 'instance-reboot'|'system-reboot'|'system-maintenance'|'instance-retirement'|'instance-stop'`

Comment: Why downvote for a potential duplicate? He has been careful enough to ask question with enough details..

Comment: @HarshTrivedi  Maybe because *"This question does not show any research effort..."*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work. You should use `in` instead of `consists`. There is nothing called `consists` in python.

```
"ab" in "abc"
#=> True

"abxyz" in "abcdf"
#=> False
```

So in your code:

```
if inst['Events'][0]['Code'] == "instance-stop":
      if '[Completed]' in inst['Events'][0]['Description']
          # the string [Completed] is present
          print "Nothing to do here"
```

Hope it helps : )

Comment: `in` is a keyword, not a method.

Comment: No need to check for `!= None` and that is not the correct way to check for it. It should be `is not None`.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this works

```
   elif inst ['Events'][0]['Code'] == "instance-stop":
                        if "[Completed]" in inst['Events'][0]['Description']:
                            print "Nothing to do here"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that the `'Events'` key has a list of dictionaries as value, you can iterate through all of them instead of hardcoding the index.

Also, `inst ['Events'][0]['Code'] == "instance-stop":` will not be true in the example you provided.

Try to do it this way:

```
for key in inst['Events']:
    if 'instance-stop' in key['Code'] and '[Completed]' in key['Description']:
        # do something here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in inst['Events']:
    if ( "instance-stop" in row['Code'].split('|')) and ((row['Descripton'].split(' '))[0] == '[Completed]'):
        print "dO what you want !"
```